How can I fix the problem that listview(+content : gridview) Style.Trigger does not working
This is C#/xaml WPF Code and I want to using materialdesign, using Trigger to change background
But I can't fix the problem that Styl.Triggers do not working. Please fix and give me a solution
MainWindow.xaml
<ListView Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="networkStatusList"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource colorListViewItem}">

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Header="상태" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate_Connect}" />

            <GridViewColumn Header="IP / Port" CellTemplate ="{StaticResource CellTemplate_IP_Port}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

App.xaml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Default" TargetType='{x:Type ListViewItem}'>
    <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}"/>
</ControlTemplate>



<Style x:Key="colorListViewItem" TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Default}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="X">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFCCCC" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Connect}" Value="O">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCFFCC" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Connect}" Value="✔">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCFFCC" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate_Connect">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Connect}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<GridViewColumn x:Key="GridViewColumn_Connect" Header="상태"
        CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate_Connect}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate_IP_Port">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IP}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Port}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>


mouse hover event, click event (material design) did not working, no effect, no color
trigger did not working

Most often, the colors of elements in a state other than normal are determined by triggers in the Control Template. These triggers usually use some resources with predefined keys.
As far as I know, there are a lot of such resources in materialdesign (hundreds or even thousands). Therefore, you need to find among them those that are used specifically in your element with its theme and its style (template).
If there are no suitable keys, then you will have to get the Element Template and make the required changes to it.
Another way is to assign the required visualization not to the element itself, but to its contents. In this case, this can be done in the Data Template:
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate_Connect">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbl" Text="{Binding Connect}"/>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="X">
            <Setter TargetName="tbl" Property="Background" Value="#FFCCCC" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Connect}" Value="O">
            <Setter TargetName="tbl" Property="Background" Value="#CCFFCC" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Connect}" Value="✔">
            <Setter TargetName="tbl" Property="Background" Value="#CCFFCC" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

The XAML code is a demonstration. I am writing the answer from my phone, so I can't guarantee that there are no errors in it. But I think it is enough for you to understand how this can be implemented.
